# Sqlite adds double quotes when importing tabular file?

Tags: import, sqlite

Annoyingly, sqlite3 adds quotes to a entries in a tabulated text file where commas, periods or parentheses are present in the entry. The code I use is:

.mode tabs
.import ./file.txt TableForFile

Which gives me, as an example the following, where the first entry is what is in the text file

- Nature --> Nature
- science (new york, n.y.) --> "science (new york, n.y.)"

This is keeping me from being able to do joins properly in my database

Comment: For completeness, show how the import is being done. Also **ensure that the quotes *do not* appear in the data *when opened in a text editor***. Escaping like that is common when a TSV/CSV file is *written*.

Comment: Ah, good catch!  I have no idea why excel adds quotes when making a tab delimited file.  very annoying

Answer (score 1):

Excel actually exports the spreadsheet by adding quotes, so it is not an import issue in sqlite3.  I will have to go through and edit the file taking quotes out then import and it should work fine.